# MarkLogic Java: Set Query Type to Value in StringQueryDefinition

Tags: marklogic

I'm using the MarkLogic Java API. I'm looking for a way to set the Query Type of a StringQueryDefinition. The type should be "Value", as described in: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/searchdev#id_34905.

> Value: Match an entire literal value, such as a string or number, in a specific JSON property or XML element. By default, value queries use exact match semantics. For example, a search for 'mark' will not match 'Mark Twain'.

I need this because I want my text searches to match only the exact search terms.

Example: the search for 'mark' should ONLY match with documents containing exactly the term 'mark' attached to some key. So, `{"anExample1": {"key1": "mark", "key2":"someotheralue"}}` is a valid match. But `{"anExample2": {"key1": "mark twain", "key2":"someotheralue"}}` is not a valid match.

For both examples, I'd like to get the URI and location within the document returned. Hence, the search for `"mark"` should return `uri/anExample1` and `anExample1/key1`.

Comment: Did you try anything?  I'm not clear under what scenario you could search for "one two three" and have it match your second example document.

Comment: You're right. My example was a bad one, sorry for that. Edited.

Comment: Make sure to also take a look at StructuredQueryBuilder and SearchHandle.  Those are probably going to be a part of your answer.  Have you read through the Java Guide for search? http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches

Comment: I did. No luck unfortunately. I don't want to pre-specify on what key(s) the search value should match.  As a return from the search I only want documents containing the exact value attached to some key within the document.

Comment: What would be the command if I do pre-specify the key? So in the example, I would search for "key1" == "mark". Not very elegant but we could attach an extra key (i.e. "extrakey") to all the values for all documents and then search for "extrakey" == "searcedValue".

Answer (score 1):

Try adding double-quotes around your string query `queryMgr.newStringDefinition().withCriteria("\"one two three\"");`

StringQueryDefinition queries follow the rules documented in [The Default String Query Grammar](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/string-query#id_23164) in the Search Guide.

Answer (score 1):

To search for "key1" = "mark" you'd do the following:

```
StructuredQueryBuilder sqb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
QueryDefinition query = sqb.value(sqb.element("key1"), "mark");
SearchHandle results = queryMgr.search(query, new SearchHandle());
```

From the results you can get the uri:

```
results.getMatchResults()[i].getUri()
```

And the match locations:

```
results.getMatchResults()[i].getMatchLocations()[j].getPath()
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a little. Unfortunately the original question is still open because eventually I want to search for exactly 'mark' without knowing which key it matches to. I will try to attach an extra key everywhere in my data which is the same everywhere but this is going to pollute my original data with this key.

Comment: Another option you could consider is creating a field which encapsulates the list of possible elements.  Then you could do the above, but substitute `sqb.field("catchall")` where it says `sqb.element("key1")`. It shouldn't be impossible to enumerate them.  And that wouldn't polute your data.